# C# add extra parameter in the handler of an event

Tags: c#

In C#/Unity, is there a way to pass more arguments to an event handler that were not specified in the delegate?

Assume that I cannot modify the delegate. (It comes from an external class.)

I need to be able to do this so I can unsubscribe from my handler later (`onClick -= HandleClick` somewhere else in the code).

Example:

```
delegate void A(str s);

event A onClick;

Awake() {
 onClick += HandleClick;
}

void HandleOnClick(str s, int a) {
   // How to get access to this second argument a here?
}
```

I know I can do the following:

```
int a = 10;
onClick += (s) => HandleOnClick(s, 10);
```

But this won't let me unregister the lambda (since it's an anonymous delegate) if I wire it up this way.

Comment: A delegate defines a function prototype. In other words, it creates a contract between the "caller" and "called" that the one supplies what the other needs (both directions). If you want another argument, you either need to create a new delegate or you need an intermediate function that matches the delegate and gets the needed, extra value(s) for the primary function.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can try to use a variable to hold the delegate reference which is able to subscribe or unsubscribe from the event.

```
Awake() {
  int a = 10;
  var e1 = (s) => HandleOnClick(s, a);
  onClick += e1;
 
  onClick -= e1;
}
```

Comment: There's 1 small additional layer of complexity. "a" keeps changing over time.
So I'm assuming I'll have to keep re-registering the lambda because of that? Not sure. 
Does it make sense to declare `a` as an instance variable and then when it changes (when I re-initialize), can I expect it to work?